# Sitecore SXA JSON Layout. Why some datasources are not serialized?

Tags: sxa, layout-service

I have `Sitecore SXA website 9.2 + 1.9`. I have a page that is built from partial designs. Partial designs contain many components. **I want to get JSON layout.** I open some page http://somewebsite/testjson?sc_device=json

**Expected result:** All controls that have data source should have `contents` value.

**Actual result**: Some of the controls have `contents` values. Some don't

I have compared `renderings/templates/datasource`, but haven't found the reason.
[image]